# Why FromBody fill default value, but DeserializeObject throw an error when null value is passed(for not nullable datatype)?

Tags: c#, .net, json-deserialization, frombodyattribute

I am creating POST API in .NET. I have following class.

```
public class Item
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

Following is the controller method.

1st approach:-

```
public IHttpActionResult Post([FromBody]Item item)
{
    // some code

    return Ok();
}
```

2nd approach:-

```
public IHttpActionResult Post()
{
    Item item = null;
    var reqContent = Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
    if (reqContent != null)
    {
        item = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Item>(reqContent);
    }

    // some code

    return Ok();
}
```

The problem is when I send `age=''` or `age=null` in a request, In the first approach, it takes `item.Age=0` but in the second approach, it throw an exception `Error converting value {null} to type 'System.Int32'.`

Why this is happening that I am not able to understand.

My guess is that in `FromBody` null value handling for such type of conversation is handle, but in `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` it is not handled.

Is it right? Or there is some other reason for the upper behavior.